# Как сделать импорт компонентов в React более аккуратным?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Использую create-react-app

Часто требуется, например, кнопка. И импортируется она, исходя из текущей папки:

```
import Button from "../../../common/Button/Button"
```

Как сделать аккуратнее импорт? Может быть всегда абсолютный путь, относительно src? Прошу поделиться опытом

Comment: это нормально так то

Comment: В целом, наверное, да. Но хотелось бы сделать удобнее

Comment: Что в вашем понимании удобнее?

Comment: можно попробовать навигацию от root-овой папки

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko например абсолютный путь будет хороший решением? или просто поделиться опытом как обычно вы делаете

Comment: @Быстрыйлось можно, посоветуйте, как лучше

Answer (score 2):

Относительно корня проекта

```
import 'foo' from '~/components/foo.js';
```

Answer (score 1):

Выбор пути импорт зависит от импортируемой сущности.

Допустим, у нас есть компонент и файл стилей к нему. Если этот файл стилей больше нигде не используется и находится рядом с компонентом, то удобно и логично использовать относительный путь.

`import Button from "./button.css"`

Допустим, у нас есть компонент и есть общий компонент. Этот общий компонент может находится в общей папке и использоваться во многих других компонентах. Тогда логичнее использовать абсолютный путь.

`import Button from "src/shared/button"`

Comment: Согласен, именно так и нужно: чтобы файл стилей компонента импортировался по относительному пути. А общие компоненты - по абсолютному. Посоветуйте, как можно так сделать?

Comment: @stiv Как сделать - зависит от вашей IDE. Я например, для каждого проекта использую набор горячих клавиш, который вставляет абсолютный путь для общей папки компонентов\библиотек. А по умолчанию импорт относительный стоит.

Comment: использую phpstorm, хотелось бы увидеть конкретный пример

Comment: @stiv конкретный пример чего вы хотите?